# How can I scroll through an array under the current situation?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of strings, and I want to set them up, so the user can scroll through the strings, and which ever one it lands on that one is selected, but I am unsure on how to do it. I was thinking of using a scroll view or a pagevc, but those take up the whole view, and it will show one string per page. Instead I need them side by side so I can see the value one ahead or one behind. A roadmap on how to execute this would be perfect, I am so lost on this component. [image: How scrolling through should look like]

```
func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    //getInfo()

     return animal.count
}

func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var labelsubject: UILabel
    var itemView: UIImageView
    var labelname: UILabel
    var cardimage: UIImageView
    var cardtypeimage: UIImageView

    if(view == nil){
        itemView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:400, height:100))
        itemView.image = UIImage(named: "page")
        itemView.contentMode = .Center

        labelsubject = UILabel(frame: itemView.bounds)
        labelsubject.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        labelsubject.textAlignment = .Center
        labelsubject.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        labelsubject.tag = 1
        itemView.addSubview(labelsubject)

    }else{
        itemView = view as! UIImageView;
        labelsubject = itemView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel!

    }

    selectedData.anim = animal[index]
        return itemView



}

func carouselDidEndDragging(carousel: iCarousel, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    if !decelerate {
        print(carousel.currentItemIndex)
        //text[carousel.currentItemIndex]
    }
}

func carouselDidEndDecelerating(carousel: iCarousel) {
    print(carousel.currentItemIndex)
    //text[carousel.currentItemIndex]
}
```

Comment: Take a look at iCarousel - https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: you can use scrollView...

Comment: @Paulw11 I attempted to use iCarousel, but I still end up getting 1 label per view, so instead Pig will be on its own swipe to right and you would see whale, but on its own. I will post my code.

Comment: Yes, you would have one word per view, but three views visible on screen at any time.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't follow

Comment: In `viewForItemAtIndex` you return a view that is 1/3 of the width of the iCarousel view, so you can see three items on screen at any instant

Comment: I created an example here - https://bitbucket.org/paulw11/carouseltest  You will need to run `pod install` after downloading the repo in order to get iCarousel

Comment: Any reason why I am getting a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` http://puu.sh/ohBk0/793bc43301.png

Comment: Are you using a `WordView` as your view in the carousel?  If not then the forced downcast will fail.